# Button extension to Data Table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to add buttons to my data table like 'copy','excel','pdf','print', and 'csv', but after running the code, I only get 'copy','csv','pdf', and 'print' and the buttons do not work. Please what am I doing wrong? I have the latest version of shiny. Here is the code below:

```
 output$Tab<-renderDataTable(
        server=FALSE,
        data.frame(
          "People"=people,
          "Industries"=industries,
          "Schools"=schools,
         "Hospitals"=hospitals),
        extensions=c('Buttons','AutoFill','ColReorder','KeyTable','Responsive'),options=list(dom='Bfrtip',buttons=list(
          'copy','pdf','csv','excel','print'),autoFill=TRUE,colReorder=TRUE,keys=TRUE)

      )
```

Answer (score 1):

`extensions` and `options` are arguments for `datatable()`, not `renderDataTable()`. See examples in the DataTables Extensions [article](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html). You could just wrap your `data.frame`, `options`, and `extensions` in `datatable()` and your code will work.

However, it might be more readable to build the `datatable` separately and then just call the object in the render.

Also, per the docs for [shiny DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html), it is recommended that you use `renderDT` instead of `renderDataTable` to avoid possible collisions with functions of the same names in shiny.

I might do something like this:

```
library(DT)

my_table <- DT::datatable(
    data.frame(
        "People"=people,
        "Industries"=industries,
        "Schools"=schools,
        "Hospitals"=hospitals),
    extensions=c('Buttons','AutoFill','ColReorder','KeyTable','Responsive'),
    options=list(dom='Bfrtip',
                 buttons=list('copy','pdf','csv','excel','print'),
                 autoFill=TRUE,
                 colReorder=TRUE,
                 keys=TRUE)
)

output$Tab<-renderDT(
    server=FALSE,
    my_table
)
```